# Issue with making react native run

Tags: android, react-native, installation

Information source to install: 
 - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Also, I have added environment variables.

Then used these commands, which runs perfectly:

> npm start
>   npm run android

then when I run this command:

> react-native run-android

It shows this `error`:
[Image showing error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2eOs.png)

```
D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
    Scanning 768 folders for symlinks in D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject\nod
    e_modules (31ms)
    Starting JS server...
    Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
    Debug)...

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build file 'D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' li
    ne: 1

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : U
    nsupported major.minor version 52.0

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
    option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 3.124 secs
    Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
    events.js:182
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
        at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

---

### Build gradle

```
        buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u share you gradle file? That would really help

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding the proper environment variable paths. please refer attached screenshot.

C:\Windows\System32**WindowsPowerShell\v1.0**;
C:\Users\gyrix**AppData\Roaming\npm**;
C:\Users\gyrix**AppData\Local\Yarn\bin**;
D:\Android\sdk1**platform-tools**;
E:\android-sdk**build-tools\25.0.2**;
D:\Android**sdk1**;
D:\Android\sdk1**tools**;
C:\Program Files**Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin**;

Note: Please specify the paths for folders in bold it might vary from system to system.  `enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have an error in your build.gradle file.

Without looking at the file i suppose it may have something to do with minimum android version or something like that.

This gradle file has all the information to build your android app so if it contains error you get "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."